# Intel x25-m 160Gb Showing up as "Kingston SSDNow 40Gb"

Tags: intel-x25-m

I have an Asrock x58 Extreme motherboard flashed to the latest bios (1.80). I have an Intel x25-m 160Gb (SATA slot 1) pluged in but the BIOS seems to register it as a Kingston SSDNow 40Gb. I wanted to try to update the SSD firmware but I cant get the BIOS to post when I switch into "Compatability" mode (Which intel claims is required to run their firmware updater ISO)

When I insert the Windows 7 install disk it also registers it as a 37.3Gb drive I can create a partition on.

This is a brand new system I am setting up. Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Did you buy it off eBay?

Comment: No I got it through Amazon. I am very unsure now. I'll try the drive at work, but it seems really odd

Comment: What was the end result of this?  Did you end up getting a replacement that worked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you bought the drive secondhand, the chips may have been switched out by a shady seller.  There's a pretty active market in counterfeit SSDs these days; [here is a thread](http://communities.intel.com/thread/8878;jsessionid=3BDCC9D42A7C4FD0CA2F4C33BE9B0B56.node5COMS) on the Intel community forums about counterfeit x25s.

Comment: Well I got it from Amazon (Through Tiger Direct). I am returning it and getting a new one. If it is this I would be very shocked. It seems pretty shady for that sort of company

Comment: Yeah, I hope that's not the case.  Sad thing is that anyone down the chain, even just the guy packing the box to ship, could switch it out and pocket the difference :(